# How to embed a Youtube video in LaTeX Beamer

Tags: video, youtube, vlc, beamer

How can I embed Youtube videos in presentations with Beamer? (Windows 7, editor: TeXstudio, TeXlive)

Here is what I tried so far (including internet search of cause): I already tried using vlc to download the video, which itself couldnt play the video afterwards.

I used a browser extension called video downloadhelper, but I am not really satisfied, because that doesn't use the source. Instead it makes a video of the screen.

I tried using the `\movie{}{}` command, but it doesn't want to work. TeXstudio (my editor) tells me:

> You clicked on a video, but the video playing mode was disabled by you or the package creator.
>
> Recompile TeXstudio with the option PHONON=true.

I didn't yet try to compile in cmd, but I will try that later today.

Thanks in advance.

edit:
I got the source for the youtube video via firefox with right click, inspect element, copy video url.
Still vlc cant read anything converted with vlc.

Comment: Check out the media9 package, http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/media9/doc/media9.pdf

Comment: @Nicky Mattsson Does media9 work better than multimedia?

Comment: I do not know, but the documentation for the media9 include a complete example on how to include a youtube video.

Comment: A bit of bibliography: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1574/embedding-videos-and-animations , http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89088/how-to-embed-video-and-animation-in-latex-and-latex-beamer-step-by-step and above all: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14751/is-it-possible-to-embed-a-youtube-video-using-latex

Comment: Linked on CTAN: http://www.math.uakron.edu/~dpstory/yt4pdf.html